# What is the difference between pickup, job, shipment and service in jsprit

Tags: java, jsprit

I don't understand the difference between pickup, job, shipment and service in jsprit

Comment: Could you please first explain what you've already learned and already understand, then narrow down to your specific problem or misunderstanding? If we naively read your question, a simple dictionary could help. But I guess its more subtile than that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of jsprit online documentation, I opened the source code and I found the answer as follows:

**Job** is the parent interface.

**Service** and **Shipment** extends Job.

Service accepts one location whereas Shipment consists of 2 locations (**Pickup**, **Delivery**)